# Log4j not working in spark streaming's foreachRDD method

Tags: apache-spark, log4j

When I used the sparkstreaming of spark2.4 to consume kafka, I found that my logs outside the foreachRDD method were printed, but the logs inside the foreachRDD were not printed. The log api I am using is log4j which version is 1.2.

I have tried adding
 
*spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties 

spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties* 
to the spark-defaults.properties configuration file, and at the beginning I wrote the wrong path when the log level and log configuration file path error information are printed
So the spark.executor.extraJavaOptions and spark.driver.extraJavaOptions configuration came into effect.

Answer (score 1):

Log inside and outside `foreach` block is executed on different machines, one is on the driver and the other one is on the executor. So if you want to see log inside `foreach` block, you can visit yarn for more logs.

Comment: Seems I am wrong, may you show the screenshot of the log(detail and yarn)? I think that will help us to find the cause.

Answer (score -1):

```
<code>
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/vdir/mnt/disk2/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/filecache/494/__spark_libs__3795396964941241866.zip/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    19/01/10 14:17:16 ERROR KafkaSparkStreamingKafkaTests: receive+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
</code>

    My code:
<code>
    1.if (args[3].equals("consumer1")) {
                logger.error("receive+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                SparkSQLService sparkSQLService = new SparkSQLService();
                consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumer1");
                sparkSQLService.sparkForwardedToKafka(sparkConf,
                        CONSUMER_TOPIC,
                        PRODUCER_TOPIC,
                        new HashMap<String, Object>((Map) consumerProperties));
    ......
    2.public void sparkForwardedToKafka(SparkConf sparkConf, String consumerTopic, String producerTopic, Map<String, Object> kafkaConsumerParamsMap) {
            sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(new Class[]{SparkSQLService.class, FlatMapFunction.class, JavaPairInputDStream.class, Logger.class});
            JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.milliseconds(DURATION_SECONDS));
            Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList(consumerTopic);
            JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> streams =
                    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                            javaStreamingContext,
                            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                            ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topics, kafkaConsumerParamsMap)
                    );
            if (producerTopic != null) {
                JavaPairDStream<Long, String> messages = streams.mapToPair(record -> new Tuple2<>(record.timestamp(), record.value()));
     messages.foreachRDD(rdd ->
                        {
                            rdd.foreachPartition(partition -> {
                                partition.forEachRemaining(tuple2 -> {
                                    LOGGER.error("****"+tuple2._1+"|"+tuple2._2);
                                    KafkaService.getInstance().send(producerTopic, TaskContext.get().partitionId(), tuple2._1, null, tuple2._2);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                );

</code>
```

And my logger declared:
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SparkSQLService.class);